# Select all Filters from Products which belongs to one Category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationships

I have these tables:

- Category
- Line
- Product
- Filter
- Product_filter

Category -> Line -> Product -> Filter

One product has many filters

One product has one category and one line

I need to get all the filters for one category.
Today, through relationships between the tables, I can get all the products from on category and all the filters from one product:

```
// All the products
$category->products

// All the filters
$product->filters

//or
$category->products->first()->filters
```

Now, I need to get the filters by category, something like:

```
$category->filters
// or
$category->products->filters
```

A small brief:

- A category has products who have filters

How to get all the filters by Category?

Comment: You will need to use JOINS for this. Just updated my answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Category` model:

```
public function filters()
{
    return Filter

        ::join('filter_product', 'filter.id', '=', 'filter_product.filter_id')

        ->join('products', 'filter_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')

        ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')

        ->where('categories.id', $this->id);
}

public function getFiltersAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->relationLoaded('products') || 
        !$this->products->first()->relationLoaded('filters')) {
        $this->load('products.filters');
    }

    return collect($this->products->lists('filters'))->collapse()->unique();
}
```

Then you will be able to use it like this:

```
$category->filters
```

To guarantee unique `filter` results, you need to pass the unique fields, for ex. `id`:

```
return collect($this->products->lists('filters'))->collapse()->unique('id');
```

Comment: In your example you have `Product_filter`, you may want to update the JOINS is that is correct. By default Laravel would use the `filter_product` table for this relation.

Comment: I tested and seems to work, @crabbly, but I'm not getting distinct results.

Comment: Its because of the pivot table data. Even though the `filter` is the same, the pivot data isn't, therefore, the `unique` method won't filter it.

Comment: Just pass the fields you want to the `unique` method, probably the easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need the with clause:

```
$category->with(products.filters)->get()
```

Comment: Not exactly, @Everton Mendonça. With your code, I'm getting the categories. What I need are the filters by Category. But now, I don't have a connection between the filters and a category. I have no idea how to do this relationship.